# Java Set Icon In class and get in Frame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource

I have a project to hand in by tomorrow and been working all day to fix a problem.
My icon for the Jframe is set but when i run netbeans to build JAR it is not able to get the Icon I have set. When just running it on netbeans it works fine. When running jar Image is not able to show.

My code is as follows for Access Class:

```
public class LigacaoBD {
public ImageIcon icone;
protected BufferedImage imgicone;

public LigacaoBD() {
    try {
        imgicone = ImageIO.read(new File("build/classes/Img/logo.png"));
        icone = new ImageIcon(imgicone);


    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro no carregamento da imagem icone", jftitulo,
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, icone);
    }
}

}
```

My code is as follows for the Jframe i want to set the icon for:

```
setIconImage(ligaDB.imgicone);
```

I am after it been able to load the icon when running the JAR.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The image needs to be bundled within the Jar file, how you do that will depend on your IDE, for example, in Netbeans, you can simply add the images to the `src` directory, in Maven, they need to be included in the `resources` directory.  In any case, once you have that, you can then use `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/logo.png"))` to load the image

Comment: I have the images inside like this src/img/logo.png

Comment: Now i changed to ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/logo.png"));

My JAR will not run at all

Comment: Did you make sure the image is included within the Jar?

Answer (score 0):

The image must be in the src folder, then I usually load it like this:
`ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img_folder/icon.png"));`

p.s: `img_folder` is inside `src`